# Как отловить разблокировку по отпечатку пальца?

Tags: java, android, fingerprint

Есть способ отловить включение/выключение экрана с помощью SCREEN_ON и SCREEN_OFF, соответственно.

Но данный способ не работает при разблокировки с помощью отпечатка пальца, то есть ловлю SCREEN_ON, но он не приходит в данном случае

Как поймать разблокировку по отпечатку пальца?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы вам советовал отлавливать любую разблокировку, а не именно по отпечатку. Потому что отпечаток поймать вы не сможете на уровне системы, а пытаться что-то лепить в виде костылей может быть очень затруднительно. В системе есть такая штука, как `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` именно при помощи данного intent-а можно поймать разблокировку экрана и делать дальше что вам нужно. [Вот](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT) документация по данной функции. Так же есть еще один способ - сделать ресивер который будет отлавливать разблокировку, а не только включение экрана:

```
public class PhoneUnlockedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)){
            Log.d(TAG, "Phone unlocked");
        }else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){
            Log.d(TAG, "Phone locked");
        }
    }
}
```

и нужно дальше добавить в активность данный код:

```
registerReceiver(new PhoneUnlockedReceiver(), new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"));
```

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446202/android-detect-phone-unlock-event-not-screen-on) вопрос по вашей тематике, может поможет при поисках. Еще [статья_1](http://chandan-tech.blogspot.com/2010/10/handling-screen-lock-unlock-in-android.html) где тоже есть полезная информация.

Comment: Спасибо, не знала о таком Intent'e. Вы абсолютно правы