# Как сделать приложение которое блокирует телефон (не дает войти в телефон) в промежутке времени

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, service, android-service

Кто нибудь может подсказать как сделать приложение которое блокирует телефон (не дает войти в телефон) в промежутке времени? к примеру пользователь не хочет чтобы там его жена или кто-то еще смотрел в его телефон пока его нет или он спит и мы в приложений ставим с какого времени заблокировать и когда разблокировать (но мне нужно понять как мне его заблокировать и разблокировать)!
Спасибо заранее!

Мой сервис

```
    package app.beer.wacklock

import android.app.Service
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.PixelFormat
import android.os.Build
import android.os.IBinder
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.view.WindowManager


const val WAKE_LOCK_TAG = "my_wake_lock_tag"

class LockService : Service() {

    lateinit var wl: WakeLock
    var mWindowManager: WindowManager? = null
    var isShowing = false
    var mView: View? = null
    var mThread: Thread? = null

    var mReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
            val action = intent.action
            if (action == Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON) {
                if (isShowing) {
                    if (mThread == null || mThread != null && !mThread!!.isAlive)
                        mThread = object : Thread() {
                            override fun run() {
                                try {
                                    sleep(1000)
                                    mWindowManager!!.removeView(mView)
                                    isShowing = false
                                } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                                    e.printStackTrace()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    mThread!!.start()
                }
            }
            if (action == Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) {
                if (!isShowing) {
//                    val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
//                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
//                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
//                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
//                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
//                                or  // Draws over status bar
//                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
//                        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
//                    )

                    val layout_parms: Int = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
                    } else {
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE
                    }

                    val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        layout_parms,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
                    )
                    mWindowManager!!.addView(mView, params)
                    isShowing = true
                }
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        mView = View(this)
        mView?.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
        mWindowManager = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
//        val pm = (getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager).also {
//            wl = it.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, WAKE_LOCK_TAG)
//        }
//        wl.acquire(10 * 60 * 1000L)
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)
        //intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
        intentFilter.priority = 999
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter)
        super.onCreate()
        Log.d("LockService", "onCreate()")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        if (isShowing) mWindowManager!!.removeView(mView)
        if (mThread != null && mThread!!.isAlive) mThread!!.interrupt()
        // wl.release()
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver)
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.d("LockService", "onDestroy()")
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.d("LockService", "onStartCommand()")
        return START_STICKY
    }

}
```

Comment: Если бы такая возможность была то на следующий день все телефоны были бы заблокированы вирусом от студента

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону самодельного экрана блокировки. Например [здесь](https://dajver.blogspot.com/2013/12/android_24.html), (надо в `MyService.java` добавить проверку на время в методе `onCreate()` после `filter.addAction(...)`).

Comment: Да, я уже так сделал

Comment: Но теперь возникает вопрос как мне запретить чтобы пользователь когда проводит вниз где statusbar и там выскакивает system navigation menu его нужно убрать, а изначально оно убрано

Comment: И еще как-то отменить сканирование отпечатка пальца (если знаешь было бы очень хорошо)

Comment: Гляньте [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1067021/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86%D0%B0).